# How to Design a large columns table

Tags: usability, tables, data-tables

I have a table in which i need to include **20-30 columns** in every row with proper font-size and padding. The Problem is few columns of the table will go out of screen. Is there any alternate for **design** such types of large columns table which is good for **usability** also.
Scrolling horizontally out of the screen is not a good option.

**Thanks In Advance......**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Display Too Much Data](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/how-to-display-too-much-data), [tables with lots of columns](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/tables-with-lots-of-columns) and/or [Best way to display more table columns and rows than I have room for?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22441/best-way-to-display-more-table-columns-and-rows-than-i-have-room-for?lq=1),

Comment: problem with me i need to display 25 columns to every user @MattObee

Comment: is it the same 25 columns for every user? maybe offer a way to let the user pick columns to display?

Comment: It is same for every user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running into the same issues quite recently at work, I followed these steps to reduce horizontal size, and try to adapt the content to smaller (or wide enough) screens:

1. Reduce font size from 1em to 0.9em. The change is slim, but enough to reduce up to 2-3 columns when you have a lot of them.
2. Analyse exactly the priority of each columns, and start hiding them according to available horizontal space.
3. Once you reach a certain point of "compression" of your table, and only if you have much more columns than rows (which was my case) you can consider inverting the axis of the table.

As stated in the possible duplicates of this post, it is quite uncommon for tables to **necessarily** require to display all the columns simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Quite often when users have a requirement to display loads of columns, what they *really* mean is that every individual user has a *different subset of columns* that are important to them.

In this scenario it can be useful to let users configure their own column order and layout (i.e. they can choose what columns to hide), so each user can see exactly what they need without impacting on the usability for all users.