# UI Patterns for tables with many columns

Tags: design-patterns, tables, html

I have a table with many columns,this table displays without scroll only on 21 inch and larger monitors.

If there is a ui pattern for tables with many columns?

Comment: First thing I'd consider is whether all of those columns are really necessary. Do you really need to present that much data in one view? Complex tables with lots of columns are often inherently difficult to decipher, even without the added problem of horizontal scrolling.

Comment: This columns is project parameters, so i need to display them in one view for user to compare them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of questions on this topic, such as [this one about How To Display Too Much Data](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/how-to-display-too-much-data) which has lots of good ideas. It really comes down to content and context; what sort of data does the table include and how/when/by whom that data is used. You mention in your comment that it shows "project parameters". As I said in my comment, you should really consider whether all of these parameters are relevant to all users.

If you consider an application like Google Analytics which needs to display very complex data and allow the user to make comparisons over that data, it tends to be split over multiple views with each view showing a discrete subset of data that's easy to digest by users with particular needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, problem was solved with configurable columns(show/hide).