# How to best display a lot of information or data on a single webpage?

Tags: website-design, layout, hierarchy, content

Are there any "rules" or recommendations in UX Design for displaying a lot of data on a webpage? Or how to select the most needed information to display data?

Comment: You might look at sites similar to yours. Social sites like Facebook, Twitter, and Pinterest all show tons of information on a single page. Or are you doing something like Amazon, which also shows a lot of info on a single product-detail page. Or are you doing something like an analytics site?

Comment: Also, there is a question about "too much data" on the site: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/how-to-display-too-much-data

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I often get jobs where i have to display a lot of content on one page. Sometimes the content types are products of a company, sometimes it's just a lot of text (articles etc). Given that it's very difficult to get a clean look and work with whitespaces to separate the content for a better user experience. I know the 10 usability rules of jakob nielsen but it's not helping for a bigger amount of content. I just wanted to know if somebody made up some good rules for these problems.

Comment: I would say that if there was a rule, that it would be not to display too much information on a single page (it leads to other debates like whether you should paginate or scroll continuously as well), and there are always ways to optimize the content on a page so that it is suitable for scanning and reading. Putting too much content on a page will prevent the application of most good design practices. The only exception might be if you want to deliberately create the appearance of having a lot of content (e.g. advertising or listing site), but it doesn't seem to improve the user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of the time, it's most useful to summarize your data into **visuals** and **higher-level categories** that allow you to drill down to the specific data.  This is why infographics are so powerful and why sites like mint.com are loved.

Categorizing your data in **mutually exclusive, collectively exhaustive** (MECE) ways will also eliminate redundancies in what you're displaying while also making sure what is displayed is thorough.  For example, make sure to segment your data into say, 3-5 categories, but also provide an "Other" category that can catch anything that may not apply (this works well so long as the Other category is relatively small).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MECE_principle

You could then choose to present the most often clicked categories above the fold.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :). I definitely learned something new today.

Answer (score 3):

A quick google turns up this article: [14 Beautiful Content-Heavy Websites for Inspiration](http://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/inspiration/14-beautiful-content-heavy-websites-for-inspiration)

It offers several principles, reworded here:

**White space** – allow the content (and your visitors’ eyes) room to breathe

**Boxes, borders & graphical planes** – Segment the information into visual categories

**Intuitive search method** – Let your users jump straight to the info they need

**Grids** – Although not always necessary for comprehension, keeping content within a rigid, consistent structure helps reduce the effort required to process it

**Strong information hierarchy** – Establish a consistent design language using content types (blurbs, excerpts, call to actions)

**Visual hierarchy** – The relative importance of different content areas and elements can be visually implied in many ways, ranging from typographic treatments (headlines, sub-headings, pull-quotes, etc.), to image sizes and saturation, placement, etc.

I would add one more important thing that ties into the hierarchical points.

**User-Centric Content Decisions** - Try as best you can, via user testing and analytics, to determine what content users really want/need and use that information to influence related decisions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since i'm a developer, most of the time i don't know how to reach information about ux, since it's rarely discussed in computer science (gladly it's slowly changing). Your information are very important and precious for people like me :)

Answer (score 0):

Design principle: Organizing information https://uxplanet.org/design-principle-organizing-information-343a7ef936a8

UX Design Guidelines For Content Heavy UI https://theuxblog.com/blog/design-guidelines-for-content-heavy-ui

How to strategically plan for data-heavy UX design https://getflywheel.com/layout/plan-data-heavy-ux-design-how-to/

Comment: We see that you have many good references here. But please extract the relevant information (for the question) and add em to your answer. There is a high chance that links could get stale in the future. Thank you :)