# Best way of showing data with many columns?

Tags: website-design, data-tables

We have a website where we showcase statistics of various reports of students. There is one report for which there are many columns i.e. 13 in total and every column is important to show. However it is not fitting different screens with different height and width. An example of the same report I am attaching below, please open the image in another tab for better viewing purpose:

[image]

Tabular way definitely doesn't look good and it is hard to see the report unless one zooms in. Is there a better UX way to showcase all these data at one place which will also look good in different screen sizes?

Comment: see also https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/how-to-display-too-much-data/77059#77059

Comment: @MichaelLai This one is another good suggestion, Thank you for the link. Really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 4):

> 13 in total and every column is important to show.

I would suggest prioritizing data you want to show to the user at once.

Conduct some research and decide which out of these 13 is most important, then provide an accordion in the table rows to show additional info on demand.

[image]

Here is an article on Medium which talks in detail about handling complex data grids (The above image is from that too)

https://uxdesign.cc/design-better-data-tables-4ecc99d23356

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :-)